# Does it exist a way for autowiring any Spring @Component inside a JPA repository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, repository, spring-data-jpa, autowired

The point is i have a Custom JPA Repository which is load using "@EnableJpaRepositories", but inside of this Custom JPA repository i do autowire another Spring Bean annotated with @Component, but it never comes filled, always bringing a null reference...

I read that JPA Repository does join and share the same Spring Application Context and so it cannot see those Beans loaded by the common Application Context... Is it really true? If so, is there any way to glue them and make Custom Repositories to inject my componentes properly???

Down here the relevant code:

```
public class DefaultCrudRepository<T extends IdentifiableEntity> extends    QuerydslJpaRepository<T, BigInteger>
    implements CrudRepository<T> {

private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

private JpaEntityInformation<T, BigInteger> jpaEntityInformation;
private EntityManager entityManager;
private EntityPath<T> path;
private PathBuilder<T> builder;
private Querydsl querydsl;

@Autowired
private SortComponent sortComponent;

@Autowired
private PageComponent pageComponent;

@Autowired
private FilterComponent filterComponent;

@Autowired
private ExpandComponent expandComponent;

public DefaultCrudRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, BigInteger> jpaEntityInformation, EntityManager entityManager,
        EntityPathResolver resolver) {
    super(jpaEntityInformation, entityManager, resolver);
    this.jpaEntityInformation = jpaEntityInformation;
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.path = resolver.createPath(jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType());
    this.builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    this.expandComponent = new DefaultExpandComponent(entityManager);
    this.sortComponent = new DefaultSortComponent();
    this.filterComponent = new DefaultFilterComponent();
    this.pageComponent = new DefaultPageComponent();
    init();
}

public DefaultCrudRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, BigInteger> jpaEntityInformation,
        EntityManager entityManager) {
    this(jpaEntityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    this.jpaEntityInformation = jpaEntityInformation;
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

/*
 * private Class<?> getDomainClass(Class<?> clazz) { Type type =
 * clazz.getGenericSuperclass(); if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
 * ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type; return
 * (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; } else { return
 * getDomainClass(clazz.getSuperclass()); } }
 */

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    this.filterComponent.init(this.jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType());
    this.expandComponent.init(this.jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType());
}

@Override
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
    List<S> savedEntities = super.save(entities);
    super.flush();
    this.entityManager.refresh(savedEntities);
    return savedEntities;
}

@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    S savedEntity = super.save(entity);
    super.flush();
    if (!this.jpaEntityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.entityManager.refresh(savedEntity);
    }
    return savedEntity;
}

protected JPQLQuery<T> createQuery(final Predicate predicate, final EntityGraph<?> entityGraph) {
    JPQLQuery<?> query = createQuery(predicate);
    if (entityGraph != null) {
        ((AbstractJPAQuery<?, ?>) query).setHint(EntityGraphType.LOAD.getKey(), entityGraph);

    }

    return query.select(path);
}

protected Page<T> findAll(final Pageable pageable, final Predicate predicate, final EntityGraph<?> entityGraph) {

    final JPQLQuery<?> countQuery = createCountQuery(predicate);
    JPQLQuery<T> query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate, entityGraph));

    return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.fetch(), pageable, new LongSupplier() {

        @Override
        public long getAsLong() {
            return countQuery.fetchCount();
        }
    });
}



@Override
public Page<T> findAll(Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize, BooleanExpression booleanExpression,
        String filterExpression, String sortExpression, String expandExpression)
        throws InvalidFilterExpressionException, InvalidSortExpressionException, 
        InvalidExpandExpressionException {

    Sort sort = null;
    if (sortExpression != null && !sortExpression.isEmpty()) {
        sort = this.sortComponent.getSort(sortExpression);
    }

    Pageable pageable = this.pageComponent.getPage(pageNumber, pageSize, sort);

    BooleanExpression filterBooleanExpression = null;

    if (filterExpression != null) {
        filterBooleanExpression = this.filterComponent.getBooleanExpression(filterExpression);
    }

    BooleanExpression mergedBooleanExpression = null;
    if (booleanExpression != null && filterBooleanExpression != null) {
        mergedBooleanExpression = booleanExpression.and(filterBooleanExpression);
    } else if (booleanExpression != null && filterBooleanExpression == null) {
        mergedBooleanExpression = booleanExpression;
    } else if (booleanExpression == null && filterBooleanExpression != null) {
        mergedBooleanExpression = filterBooleanExpression;
    }

    EntityGraph<?> entityGraph = null;
    if (expandExpression != null && !expandExpression.isEmpty()) {
        entityGraph = this.expandComponent.getEntityGraph(expandExpression);
    }

    return this.findAll(pageable, mergedBooleanExpression, entityGraph);
}

protected Predicate getPredicate(final BigInteger identifier, final Predicate predicate) {
    Class<?> clazz = this.jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType();
    String name = CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, clazz.getSimpleName());
    Path<?> rootPath = Expressions.path(this.jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType(), name);
    Class<?> idType = this.jpaEntityInformation.getIdType();
    String idAttributeName = this.jpaEntityInformation.getIdAttribute().getName();
    Path<?> leftPath = Expressions.path(idType, rootPath, idAttributeName);
    Expression<?> rightExpression = Expressions.constant(identifier);
    BooleanExpression booleanExpression = Expressions.predicate(Ops.EQ, leftPath, rightExpression);
    BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder(booleanExpression);
    booleanBuilder.and(predicate);
    return booleanBuilder.getValue();
}

protected T findOne(final BigInteger identifier, final BooleanExpression booleanExpression,
        final EntityGraph<?> entityGraph) {
    Assert.notNull(identifier, "The given id must not be null!");
    T object = null;
    if (booleanExpression != null) {
        Predicate mergedPredicate = getPredicate(identifier, booleanExpression);
        JPQLQuery<T> query = createQuery(mergedPredicate, entityGraph);
        object = query.fetchOne();
    } else {
        Map<String, Object> hints = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (entityGraph != null) {
            hints.put("javax.persistence.loadgraph", entityGraph);
        }
        object = this.entityManager.find(this.jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType(), identifier, hints);
    }
    return object;
}

@Override
public T findOne(final BigInteger identifier, final BooleanExpression booleanExpression,
        final String expandExpression) throws InvalidExpandExpressionException {

    EntityGraph<?> entityGraph = null;
    if (booleanExpression != null) {
        entityGraph = this.expandComponent.getEntityGraph(expandExpression);
    }

    return this.findOne(identifier, booleanExpression, entityGraph);
}

@Override
public Map<Number, T> findAllRevisions(final BigInteger identifier) {
    Assert.notNull(identifier, "The given id must not be null!");
    AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(this.entityManager);
    List<Number> revisionList = auditReader.getRevisions(this.jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType(), identifier);
    if (revisionList == null || revisionList.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    Set<Number> revisionSet = new LinkedHashSet<Number>(revisionList);
    return auditReader.findRevisions(this.jpaEntityInformation.getJavaType(), revisionSet);
}

@Override
public void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
    super.delete(entities);
    super.flush();
}

@Override
public void delete(T entity) {
    super.delete(entity);
    super.flush();
}
```

}

```
public class AbstractCrudService<T extends IdentifiableEntity> implements CrudService<T> {

@Autowired(required=false)
private CrudRepository<T> repository;

@Autowired(required=false)
private NotificationComponent<T> notificationComponent;

private NotificationContext<T> geNotificationContext(String action, List<T> payload) {
    DefaultNotificationContext<T> defaultNotificationContext = new DefaultNotificationContext<T>();
    /*defaultNotificationContext.setAction(action);
    defaultNotificationContext.setObject(this.domainClazz.getSimpleName());
    defaultNotificationContext.setInstant(Instant.now());
    defaultNotificationContext.setResponsibleId(null);
    defaultNotificationContext.setPayload(payload);*/
    return defaultNotificationContext;
}

private NotificationContext<T> geNotificationContext(String action, Page<T> payload) {
    return geNotificationContext(action, payload.getContent());
}

private NotificationContext<T> geNotificationContext(String action, T payload) {
    List<T> payloadList = new ArrayList<T>();
    payloadList.add(payload);
    return geNotificationContext(action, payloadList);
}

@Override
@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = LongTermRunningException.class)
@TypeTaskCriteria(pre = PreSaveTask.class, post = PostSaveTask.class, referenceGenericType = AbstractCrudService.class)
public List<T> save(List<T> objects)
        throws ConcurrentModificationException, UnexpectedException {

    List<T> savedObjectList = this.repository.save(objects);

    if (this.notificationComponent != null) {
        this.notificationComponent.notify(geNotificationContext(NotificationContext.SAVE, savedObjectList));
    }

    return savedObjectList;
}

@Override
@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = LongTermRunningException.class)
@TypeTaskCriteria(pre = PreSaveTask.class, post = PostSaveTask.class, referenceGenericType = AbstractCrudService.class)
public T save(T object) throws ConcurrentModificationException, UnexpectedException {

    T savedObject = this.repository.save(object);

    if (this.notificationComponent != null) {
        this.notificationComponent.notify(geNotificationContext(NotificationContext.SAVE, savedObject));
    }

    return savedObject;
}

@Override
@TypeTaskCriteria(pre = PreRetrieveTask.class, post = PostRetrieveTask.class, referenceGenericType = AbstractCrudService.class)
public Page<T> retrieve(
        @P(PAGE_NUMBER) final Integer pageNumber,
        @P(PAGE_SIZE) final Integer pageSize,
        @P(FILTER_EXPRESSION) final String filterExpression,
        @P(SORT_EXPRESSION) final String sortExpression,
        @P(EXPAND_EXPRESSION) final String expandExpression,
        @P(PARAMETERS) final Map<String, String> parameters) throws InvalidParameterException, UnexpectedException {

    DefaultRetrieveTaskContext context = TaskContextHolder.getContext();
    BooleanExpression booleanExpression = context.getBooleanExpression();

    Page<T> page = null;
    try {
        page = new Page<T>(this.repository.findAll(pageNumber, pageSize, booleanExpression, filterExpression, sortExpression, expandExpression));
    } catch (InvalidFilterExpressionException | InvalidSortExpressionException
            | InvalidExpandExpressionException e) {
        throw new UnexpectedException(e);
    }

    if (this.notificationComponent != null) {
        this.notificationComponent.notify(geNotificationContext(NotificationContext.RETRIEVE, page));
    }

    return page;
}

@Override
@TypeTaskCriteria(pre = PreRetrieveTask.class, post = PostRetrieveTask.class, referenceGenericType = AbstractCrudService.class)
public T retrieve(BigInteger identifyer, String expandExpression) throws NotFoundException, UnexpectedException {

    RetrieveTaskContext context = TaskContextHolder.getContext();
    BooleanExpression booleanExpression = context.getBooleanExpression();

    T object = null;
    try {
        object = this.repository.findOne(identifyer, booleanExpression, expandExpression);
    } catch (InvalidExpandExpressionException invalidExpandExpressionException) {
        throw new UnexpectedException(invalidExpandExpressionException);
    }

    if (this.notificationComponent != null) {
        this.notificationComponent.notify(geNotificationContext(NotificationContext.RETRIEVE, object));
    }   

    return object;
}

@Override
@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = LongTermRunningException.class)
@TypeTaskCriteria(pre = PreDeleteTask.class, post = PostDeleteTask.class, referenceGenericType = AbstractCrudService.class)
public void delete(List<T> objects) throws ConcurrentModificationException, UnexpectedException {

    this.repository.delete(objects);

    if (this.notificationComponent != null) {
        this.notificationComponent.notify(geNotificationContext(NotificationContext.DELETE, (List<T>) null));
    }
}

@Override
@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = LongTermRunningException.class)
@TypeTaskCriteria(pre = PreDeleteTask.class, post = PostDeleteTask.class, referenceGenericType = AbstractCrudService.class)
public void delete(T object) throws ConcurrentModificationException, UnexpectedException {

    this.repository.delete(object);

    if (this.notificationComponent != null) {
        this.notificationComponent.notify(geNotificationContext(NotificationContext.DELETE, (T) null));
    }
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "br.org.ccee", repositoryFactoryBeanClass =     CrudRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ServiceConfiguration {

@Bean
//@Scope("request")
public ServiceContext serviceContext() {
    DefaultServiceContext defaultServiceContext = new DefaultServiceContext();
    defaultServiceContext.setInstant(Instant.now());
    defaultServiceContext.setUserId(new BigInteger("33"));
    defaultServiceContext.setTenantId(new BigInteger("69"));
    return defaultServiceContext;
}

@Bean
public TenantEventListener tenantEventListener() {
    return new TenantEventListener();
}

@Bean
public AuditEventListener auditEventListener() {
    return new AuditEventListener();
}

@Bean
public EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry(
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory, 
        TenantEventListener tenantEventListener,
        AuditEventListener auditEventListener) {
    SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) entityManagerFactory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistryImplementor = sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry();
    EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistryImplementor.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.PRE_INSERT, auditEventListener);
    eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.PRE_INSERT, tenantEventListener);
    eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.PRE_UPDATE, auditEventListener);
    return eventListenerRegistry;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you talking about a JPA repository interface or a custom repository implementation? If the first, then autowiring won't work in there. If the latter, then it should work because your implementation should be a Spring bean. However, without showing any code it's hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: @dunni thank you. i´ve added the relevant part of the Repository implementation

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Also which fields are null? All of them?

Comment: Also, can you show the code where you actually use this repository class? How do you initialize it?

Comment: thanks dunni - Added source code to the first question and yes all of them Autowired fields come null as it would be out of the Spring Context. Initialization is done by package scanning... using @EnableJpaRepositories.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DefaultCrudRepository<T extends IdentifiableEntity> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, BigInteger>
        implements CrudRepository<T> {

    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private JpaEntityInformation<T, BigInteger> jpaEntityInformation;
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private EntityPath<T> path;
    private PathBuilder<T> builder;
    private Querydsl querydsl;

    @Autowired
    private SortComponent sortComponent;

    @Autowired
    private PageComponent pageComponent;

    @Autowired
    private FilterComponent filterComponent;

    @Autowired
    private ExpandComponent expandComponent;
```